# How to create a global variable in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to use a global variable in my .net project. However, i cannot handle it between two methods..

my code:

```
string str;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        str = "i am a string";
        showString();
    }
}

void showString()
{
    aspLabel.Text = str; //error
}
```

***Question update:***

I will not consider to use `showString(str)` because this variable is used many methods.. For example, I have a click event which need to use it.

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    exportToExcel(str);
}
```

Therefore, I need to create it in global!

Comment: _Therefore, i need to create it in global!_ - see my second and third code pieces for that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is don't do global variables (you also can't).

Closest to `Global` is having it in a class that is `static` and has a `static` member - but I really think it would be the wrong approach for most of the cases. `Static` classes/members usually make code more coupled and reduces testability so pick carefully when you decide to do so.

Do instead: (pass parameter)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    string str = "i am a string";
    showString(str);
  }
}

void showString(string str)
{
  aspLabel.Text = str;
}
```

Or:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private string str;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        str = "i am a string";
        showString();
      }
    }

    protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       exportToExcel(str);
    }

    void showString()
    {
      aspLabel.Text = str;
    }
}
```

*Here you can change the `str` to be a property or a different access modifier as you wish, but this is the general idea.*

*If you have it as public instead of private you will be able to access it from different classes that hold an instance to this class. like this:*

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Str { get; private set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        Str = "i am a string";
        showString();
      }
    }

    protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       exportToExcel(Str);
    }

    void showString()
    {
      aspLabel.Text = Str;
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public SomeOtherClass()
    {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        var otherStr = someClass.Str;
    }
}
```

Comment: .....I will not consider to use showString(str) because this variable is used many methods..

Comment: Are all methods in this same class? If so check edit

Answer (score 3):

As has been said, don't do global variables. Instead pass a parameter into the method.

To make it slightly more obvious what is happening:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    string str = "i am a string";
    showString(str);
  }
}

void showString(string nowthis) // nowthis == str, value is copied in
{
  aspLabel.Text = nowthis;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no notion of a global variable in C#.

You can have static members like this

```
public static class MyClassWithStatics
{
   public static string MyString {get;set;}
}
```

Then, in another class, you can reference it:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
   public void MyMethod() 
   {
       var str = MyClassWithStatics.MyString;
   }
}
```