# Group By query in mvc5

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i want to write sql Group by query in C#  of my MVC5 application.

[image: Groupby query in sql]

In the above image I have group by query which i wrote in sql . That I want to write in C# front end.

[image: C# Code]

I tried to write query in front end. But I am getting error which is mentioned in the image. Now I want to write that Group By query in C# and want to display the each employee with count (output same as mentioned in the first image). Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

My ViewModel(Dashnboard View model)

```
public class DashboardViewmodel
{
    public List<CustomerTypeCountModel> CustomerTypesCountModels { get; set; }
    public List<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
    public CustomerTypeViewModel CustomerTypeViewModels { get; set; }
    public int sizingcount { get; set; }
    public int Processingcount { get; set; }

    //here i declared two properties
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCount { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller code

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SalesVisit()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult GetDatesFromSalesVisit(DashboardViewmodel dvm)
{
    var fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dvm.CustomerTypeViewModels.FromDate);
    var todate = Convert.ToDateTime(dvm.CustomerTypeViewModels.ToDate);

    List<View_VisitorsForm> empcount = new List<View_VisitorsForm>();

   if (DepartmentID == new Guid("47D2C992-1CB6-44AA-91CA-6AA3C338447E") &&
      (UserTypeID == new Guid("106D02CC-7DC2-42BF-AC6F-D683ADDC1824") ||
      (UserTypeID == new Guid("B3728982-0016-4562-BF73-E9B8B99BD501"))))

       {

    var empcountresult = db.View_VisitorsForm.GroupBy(G => G.Employee)
                          .Select(e => new
                          {
                              employee = e.Key,
                              count = e.Count()
                          }).ToList();

        empcount = empcountresult ;//this line i am getting error 
 }
   DashboardViewmodel obj = new DashboardViewmodel();

     return View("SalesVisit", obj);
}
```

Comment: Also.. Please provide the sql and the error message instead of posing it as pictures..

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework. It has nothing to do with grouping data

Answer (score 4):

When you use a `GroupBy` you get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key,YourOriginalType>>` so you do not have `.Employee` and `.VisitingID` properties.

Change as following:

```
public class EmployeeCount
{
    public string Employee {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
}

List<EmployeeCount> result = db.View_VisitorsForm
               .Where(item => item.VisitingDate >= beginDate && item.VisitingDate < endDate)
               .GroupBy(G => G.Employee)
               .Select(e =>new EmployeeCount
               {
                   employee = e.Key,
                   count = e.Count()
               }).ToList();

//Now add the result to the object you are passing to the View
```

*Also keep in mind that you are not instantiating objects of type `View_VisitorsForm` but an anonymous object so assigning the result to `empcount` yet alone with the added `FirstOrDefault` will not compile*

To pass this structure to the View and present it check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40138355/6400526)

Comment: Gilad Green i cant understand as per  that first image i need to show each employee with count how i display that can you explain m ein detail

Comment: Gilafd Green See my sql query in that i  calculated employee and therir counts . Same like that i like to show Employee with count in front end

Comment: @Swetha - So this is that the query above does. Execute it and see

Comment: Select count(VisitingID)As Count,Employee from View_VisitorsForm where VisitingDate between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-30' Group by Employee 
 this is my sql query

Comment: ok how  i call this in view you gave me controller code i need one sample view code

Comment: Gliad Green i cant understand can you explain me in detail please

Comment: Gliad Green where i have to write this IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key,YourOriginalType>> in view??

Comment: Gliad Green wait i will explain you with some images and codes

Comment: @Swetha - No because after the `select` the type is `IEnumerable<SomeAnonymousType>`. This is a followup question.. Please search SO for how to present it.. You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40138355/6400526) from a few days ago

Comment: Gliad Green https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u2IB.jpg see this image see i showed 2 outputs Sizing and their count processing and their count like that i want to show each employee count in view

Comment: @Swetha - Check my updated answer referring you to a similar question to your followup question

Comment: so i like to used group code in front end depend upon the result i will show the output but now i donno how to write view code ddepend upon controller code

Comment: @Swetha - As in the question I referred you too - create another class that will have 2 properties of name and count and use it.

Comment: Gliad yes i created properties in particular class

Comment: My doubt is in view code i  have to give @model IEnumerable<dynamic>

Comment: @Swetha - which class? Please add it to the question

Comment: I did as per you said but i am getting error that i mention in the code and i m in confusion of creating view code

Comment: @Swetha - As explained above - you are getting error because `empcount` is a list of `View_VisitorsForm` but the linq is currently returning an anonymous type.. What I said is that you need to create a type for that kind of result and then set it.. You also can't use `DashboardViewmodel` because it doesn't represent the entire result but just 1 pair of name to count.. If you will have in it a `List<SomeType>` then change the linq to create `new SomeType` instead of the anonymous type and then you can `obj.TheList = linqResult.ToList()`

Comment: @Swetha - Did this last comment help you better understand?

Comment: you mentioning like this    List<View_VisitorsForm> empcount = new List<View_VisitorsForm>();

Comment: Gliad i need to write uyour query inside of if condition

Comment: Why because i need to show the result based on the person login if i wrote inside of if condition means how i took it outside and assign to global variable?

Comment: @Swetha - A question on SO is there to answer a single question with no followup questions. If you have new questions then seek the answer on SO (your new questions have been answered before, also by me (see previous link and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38631951/6400526) too). If after trying to solve it yourself you still can't then you can post a new question. As for this question, my answer solved it..

Answer (score -1):

hope this helps you

```
 var query = db.View_VisitorsForm.Where(o => o.VisitingDate >= new DateTime(2016,10,01) && o.VisitingDate <= new DateTime(2016, 10, 30)).GroupBy(G => G.Employee)

foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Employee Id {item.Key} : Count :{item.Count()}");
                }
```